# What is the most accurate rendering of the Hebrew of 2 Samuel 7:14?

Tags: 2-samuel

The ESV translation of 2 Samuel 7:14 is:

> I will be to him a father, and he shall be to me a son. When he commits **iniquity**, I will discipline him with the rod of men, with the stripes of the sons of men.

Blue Letter Bible states that the word translated "iniquity" in the ESV (h5753)  is a verb in a form which implies causation

https://www.blueletterbible.org/kjv/2sa/7/14/t_conc_274014

( at h5753 click on parse feature then click on stem: hiphil )

however,

a commentary written by Adam Clarke asserts that the same verb is actually written in the passive sense

https://www.studylight.org/commentaries/acc/2-samuel-7.html

copied from the above link ;

"As to the third and greatest difficulty, that also may be removed by a more just translation of 2 Samuel 7:14; for the Hebrew words do not properly signify what they are now made to speak. It is certain that the principal word, בהעותו behaavotho, is not the active infinitive of kal, which would be בעותו , but העות from עיה is in niphal, as הגלות from גלה . It is also certain that a verb, which in the active voice signifies to commit iniquity, may, in the passive signify to suffer for iniquity; and hence it is that nouns from such verbs sometimes signify iniquity, sometimes punishment....The way being thus made clear, we are now prepared for abolishing our translation, if he commit iniquity; and also for adopting the true one, even in his suffering for iniquity.

which one is correct ?

or

are the BLB and Adam Clarke both citing completely different renderings of the Hebrew words ? and if so was Adam Clarke reading from an alternate text/tradition ?

Comment: Welcome to BH. It would help if you could quote the text for us and also quote the translation of the text which the writer suggests so that we can compare the two.

Comment: 1. Where do you see the Blue Letter parsing implying "causation"? Do you mean *hiphil* as a causative form? 2. Where do you see Adam Clarke indicating a passive sense? I did not see either of these terms explicitly in those references. The ESV is spot on, but the translation of בְּהַעֲו‍ֹתוֹ is not "iniquity" but "when he commits iniquity" or just "when he sins". The ESV uses a word "commits", which is not in the MT to translate the sense of the "hiphil" form. Maybe this is what you mean by "causative".

Comment: Regrettably, this kind of question would trigger a discussion too much broad for the scope of this site (if someone has succeed to create a BH site devoted to 'Semitic Languages'...). Only to illustrate the maze of the issues around the BNINIM (called 'conjugations', according Gesenius-Kautzsch), as Qal, Pi'el, Hiph'il, Niph'al, Pu'al, Hoph'al, and Hithpa'el, I cite the fact that the Hiph'il verbal function - that we hope to be unambiguous (from the start) - is so fragmentized that the scholars assign it various meanings. (to be continued)

Comment: Regarding hiph'il - for an example, we have, among its verbal meanings the following different meanings: Causative (of Qal), Declarative, Ingressive. Even, some scholars describe it as equivalent to the Qal or the Pi'el! (personally, I reject almost all the building of these 'conjugations'. According the studies of mine Ancient Hebrew was differently structured).